# SQLite general getEntry(...) function

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm on a Java Project and programming a SQLite "Actionhandler-Class" where you can create/drop tables and add/update/get/delete Entry's in these tables.

The general creating/dropping of tables and the adding of an Entry works fine, but now I want to make the `getEntry(...)` function.

```
public void getEntry(String table, String[] ident){
    try{
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String exec = "SELECT " + ident[0] + " FROM " + table;
        if(!ident[1].isEmpty()){
            exec += " WHERE(" + ident[1] + ");";
        }else{
            exec += ";";
        }
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(exec);
        while(res.next()){
            System.out.println(res.getInt("uid"));
            System.out.println(res.getString("uname"));
            System.out.println(res.getString("pwd"));
            System.out.println(res.getString("mail"));
            System.out.println(res.getInt("rank"));
            System.out.println(res.getInt("coins"));
            System.out.println(res.getString("stg"));
        }
        res.close();
        stmt.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works, of course!
But I dont want to `System.out.println(...)` all Data, I want to give it back to the `main(...)` function which called the `getEntry(...)` function so it can work with this Data. How to give the `res` data back of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the function as `ResultSet` instead :

```
public ResultSet getEntry(String table, String[] ident){
try{
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String exec = "SELECT " + ident[0] + " FROM " + table;
        if(!ident[1].isEmpty()){
            exec += " WHERE(" + ident[1] + ");";
        }else{
            exec += ";";
        }
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(exec);
       /* while(res.next()){
            System.out.println(res.getInt("uid"));
            System.out.println(res.getString("uname"));
            System.out.println(res.getString("pwd"));
            System.out.println(res.getString("mail"));
            System.out.println(res.getInt("rank"));
            System.out.println(res.getInt("coins"));
            System.out.println(res.getString("stg"));
        }res.close();
        stmt.close();*/

return res;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then in the main you can process the ResultSet

```
 public static void main (String args []){

  YourClass yourInstance = new YourClass ();

ResultSet tempResultSet = yourInstance.getEntry();
   while( tempResultSet .next() ){
   System.out.println(res.getInt("uid"));
        System.out.println(res.getString("uname"));
        System.out.println(res.getString("pwd"));
        System.out.println(res.getString("mail"));
        System.out.println(res.getInt("rank"));
        System.out.println(res.getInt("coins"));
        System.out.println(res.getString("stg"));
  }

  yourInstance .stmt.close() ; // this is assuming stmt is public
  yourInstance.tempResultSet.close()

}
```

If there is a method returning `stmt` assuming like `getStmt()`, then you close it with `yourInstance.getStmt().close()`

Comment: Yeah, but where should i close stmt and res then, and where should i close the conn?

Comment: wait, let me modify it. according to your structure

Comment: Do you need more of my src?

Comment: Okay. And must stmt be closed after all operations on res?

Comment: Yes. @MartinFischer,(but in case you need to reuse the `stmt` then just close the `res`) Btw this is the last comment allowed, but feel free to accept my answer if it helps solves the problem, so I know this sweat is not wasted uselessly, but it's up to you.

Comment: Mustn't I also close the yourInstance.res.close() AND tempResultSet.close() ?

Comment: Can I please just ask you one question more in chat? Can you invite me to chat pls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83910/discussion-between-martin-fischer-and-fevplr).

Comment: In your code , `stmt` created statement object of connection , while `res` is object (set or rows) returned by executing the statement ( with query) , so closing `res` doesn't mean closing `stmt`, imagine you want to still use the stmt for different/new `rs` object , in that case you just need close res, you'll close everthing just after you don't need them anymore ;)